# Merging 2 dataframe using similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection, concatenation

I have 2 dataframe listed as follow

df

```
 Type       Breed     Common Color  Other Color  Behaviour
 Golden      Big           Gold          White        Fun      
 Corgi      Small          Brown         White       Crazy
 Bulldog    Medium         Black         Grey        Strong
```

df2

```
 Type              Breed    Behaviour   Bark Sound
 Pug               Small      Sleepy          Ak
 German Shepard    Big        Cool            Woof
 Puddle            Small      Aggressive      Ek
```

I wanted to merge 2 dataframe by columns `Type`, `Breed` and `Behavior`.

Therefore, my desire output would be:

```
Type           Breed      Behavior
Golden          Big         Fun
Corgi           Small       Crazy  
Bulldog         Medium      Strong
Pug             Small       Sleepy
German Shepard  Big         Cool
Puddle          Small       Aggressive
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df1[['Type','Breed','Behaviour']], 
                  df2[['Type','Breed','Behaviour']]], ignore_index=True))

             Type   Breed   Behaviour
0          Golden     Big         Fun
1           Corgi   Small       Crazy
2         Bulldog  Medium      Strong
3             Pug   Small      Sleepy
4  German Shepard     Big        Cool
5          Puddle   Small  Aggressive
```

More general is use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for columns of both `DataFrames`:

```
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
print (cols)
Index(['Type', 'Breed', 'Behaviour'], dtype='object')

print (pd.concat([df1[cols], df2[cols]], ignore_index=True))
             Type   Breed   Behaviour
0          Golden     Big         Fun
1           Corgi   Small       Crazy
2         Bulldog  Medium      Strong
3             Pug   Small      Sleepy
4  German Shepard     Big        Cool
5          Puddle   Small  Aggressive
```

More general if `df1` and `df2` have no `NaN` values use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for removing columns with `NaN`:

```
print (pd.concat([df1 ,df2], ignore_index=True))
     Bark Sound   Behaviour   Breed Common Color Other Color            Type
0        NaN         Fun     Big         Gold       White          Golden
1        NaN       Crazy   Small        Brown       White           Corgi
2        NaN      Strong  Medium        Black        Grey         Bulldog
3         Ak      Sleepy   Small          NaN         NaN             Pug
4       Woof        Cool     Big          NaN         NaN  German Shepard
5         Ek  Aggressive   Small          NaN         NaN          Puddle               


print (pd.concat([df1 ,df2], ignore_index=True).dropna(1))
    Behaviour   Breed            Type
0         Fun     Big          Golden
1       Crazy   Small           Corgi
2      Strong  Medium         Bulldog
3      Sleepy   Small             Pug
4        Cool     Big  German Shepard
5  Aggressive   Small          Puddle
```

Answer (score 3):

using `join` dropping columns that don't overlap

```
df1.T.join(df2.T, lsuffix='_').dropna().T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]